# MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file is not found

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, rider

```
PS C:\Users\vivi\RiderProjects\Catalogo> cd .\Catalogo.Infrastructure\
PS C:\Users\vivi\RiderProjects\Catalogo\Catalogo.Infrastructure> dotnet ef migrations add Inicial --project Catalogo.Infrastructure -s Catalogo.API -c ApplicationDbContext --verbose
Using project 'C:\Users\vivi\RiderProjects\Catalogo\Catalogo.Infrastructure\Catalogo.Infrastructure'.
Using startup project 'C:\Users\stefa\RiderProjects\Catalogo\Catalogo.Infrastructure\Catalogo.API'.
Writing 'C:\Users\vivi\RiderProjects\Catalogo\Catalogo.Infrastructure\obj\Catalogo.Infrastructure.EntityFrameworkCore.targets'...
dotnet msbuild /target:GetEFProjectMetadata /property:EFProjectMetadataFile=C:\Users\vivi\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp0qfpz4.tmp /verbosity:quiet /nologo C:\Users\vivi\RiderProjects\Catalogo\Catalogo.Infrastructure\Catalogo.Infrastructure
```

> MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Arquivo de projeto não existe.
> Opção: C:Users\vivi\RiderProjects\Catalogo\Catalogo.Infrastructure\Catalogo.Infrastructure
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.CommandException: Unable to retrieve project metadata. Ensure it's an SDK-style project. If you're using a custom BaseIntermediateOutputPath or MSBuildProjectExtensionsPath values, Use the --msbuildprojectextensionspath option.
>
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Project.FromFile(String file, String buildExtensionsDir, String framework, String configuration, String runtime)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.RootCommand.Execute(String[] _)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Commands.CommandBase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.b__0(String[] args)
> at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.CommandLine.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Program.Main(String[] args)
>
> Unable to retrieve project metadata. Ensure it's an SDK-style project. If you're using a custom BaseIntermediateOutputPath or MSBuildProjectExtensionsPath values, Use the --msbuildprojectextensionspath option.

- I was hoping to do the migration
- I'm using Jetbrains Rider